# PyQt5 File open Dialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

is there any way to open a folder with pyqt5 file dialog

I tried taking the quotes, I want to open a folder or a directory with subdirectories or subfolders

````
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.button1 = QPushButton('Open Project Folder')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)


        self.labelImage = QLabel()
        self.textEditor = QTextEdit()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelImage)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEditor)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def get_folder(self):
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Project Data', r"", "")
        print(file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Comment: You should use [`getExistingDirectory()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory).

Comment: but how actually i'm a newbie to pyqt5 so please help me in a brief manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various [static functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#static-public-members) available for QFileDialog, if you need to open a directory, don't use `getOpenFileName` but [`getExistingDirectory()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory).

As you can see from the documentation, the arguments are slightly different, and
if you run `help(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory)` from the python shell, you'll see the full argument signature and the returned value written in the python syntax.

> `getExistingDirectory(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', options: Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] = QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly) -> str`

The last part ( `-> str`) means that there is only one returned value, which is the *string* of the selected directory (which will be empty if the user cancels the dialog).

```
    def get_folder(self):
        folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, 'Project Data', '')
        if folder:
            print(folder)
```

<sub>I suggest you to always study the documentation of each class you're using, and using the *official* documentation; even if it's C++ oriented, the functions have the same names on PyQt, and their arguments/returned values are the same in 99% of the cases. Whenever you've a doubt or you face a problem about wrong arguments or returned data, you can check the [official PyQt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/) documentation or just use `help(class.function)` in the python shell.</sub>